# Ошибка Error inflating class fragment при нажатии на сообщение

Tags: android, kotlin, fcm

Есть приложение в которое приходят пуши (Firebase Cloud Message). Приложение нармально запускается, работает. Но когда приходит сообщение, я жму на сообщение меня перекидывает в приложение и приложение вылетает вот ошибка:

```
Process: org.fastzalm.aapp, PID: 13904
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.fastzalm.aapp/org.fastzalm.aapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #73 in org.fastzalm.aapp:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #73 in org.fastzalm.aapp:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #73 in org.fastzalm.aapp:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #73 in org.fastzalm.aapp:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #73 in org.fastzalm.aapp:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.fastzalm.aapp.MainActivity.getmToolbar(MainActivity.kt:629)
        at org.fastzalm.aapp.MainActivity.hideToolbar(MainActivity.kt:644)
        at org.fastzalm.aapp.fragments.LoansDescFragment.onCreateView(LoansDescFragment.kt:86)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:3065)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2988)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:392)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:281)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:140)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:319)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:298)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1069)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:997)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at org.fastzalm.aapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:66)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
2021-12-22 15:16:22.040 13904-13904/org.fastzalm.aapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Тут написано что ошибка в xml но там ошибок я не увидел если что то вот код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:flow_horizontalAlign="center"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:backgroundTint="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/back_toolbar_btn"
            android:src="@drawable/toolbar_src"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_width="33dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:background="@drawable/toolbar_left"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Кредитные"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
            android:fontFamily="@font/gilroy_medium"
            android:textFontWeight="800"
            android:textColor="@color/black2"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:lineHeight="25sp"
            android:letterSpacing="0.05"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
             />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:src="@drawable/toolbar_right"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@color/bkg_bottom_bar"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/mwhite"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/mwhite"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="selected"
        />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Вот немного MainActivity но там после  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) дальше не идет процесс.

```
@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        //тут уже вылетело приложение
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        if(intent!=null && intent.extras != null) {
            Log.i("TAG_I", intent.extras.toString())
            var link = intent.extras!!.getString("link")
            if(!link.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                var destination = MyFirebaseMessagingService.getId(applicationContext, link)
                if(destination != null) {
                    var idForBundle = MyFirebaseMessagingService.getBundleId(
                        applicationContext,
                        link
                    )
                    if(idForBundle != null) {
                        val bundle = Bundle()
                        bundle.putInt("id", idForBundle!!)
                        navController.navigate(destination, bundle)
                    } else {
                        navController.navigate(destination)
                    }
                }


            }
        }
        toolbar = getmToolbar()
        fragment = getmView()
//тут еще код но он сюда не доходит вылетает
}
 fun getmToolbar(): Toolbar {
        if(toolbar == null) {
            toolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar)
        }
        return toolbar!!
    }

 fun getmView(): View {
     if(fragment == null) { /*!this::fragment.isInitialized*/
        fragment = findViewById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as View
     }
     return fragment!!
 }
```

Не могу понять что не так ведь раньше то работало.

Comment: что в getmToolbar? судя по логам, проблема там

Comment: Нет проблема не там до этих функций даже не доходит. Но действительно я допишу Я дописал

Comment: Судя по стеку этот метод вызывается из фрагмента во время выполнения `setContentView()`. То есть разметка в процессе разбора и ещё не добавлена на экран, соответственно `findViewById` ничего не может найти. Попробуйте перенести сокрытие тулбара (во фрагменте) в другой метод, только не могу сказать где он уже будет доступен. Лучше бы наверное добавлять фрагмент не тэгом в макет, а кодом через `FragmentManager` или через `NavController` (не заметил сразу что вы его используете)

Comment: Лучше бы наверное добавлять фрагмент не тэгом в макет, а кодом через FragmentManager или через NavController (не заметил сразу что вы его используете) Спасибо интерестная идея надо будет попробовать, потому что ошибку в макете показывает именно там где тег <fragment> , что интерестно будет если кодом добавить. А из макета вообще удалить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причину как не странно мне написали в самих логах. Дело в том что после `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` вызывалось создание фрагмента, который брался из PendingIntent. А в самом этом фрагменте в `onCreateView` вызвалась функция из самой `MainActivity` `callbackActivity?.hideToolbar()`, т.к. самого заполнения макета еще не произошло а в этой функции шло обращение к макету, то появлялось исключение и приложение вылетало. Решил проблему очень просто: перенес вызов этих функций в `onActivityCreated`:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        callbackActivity?.hideToolbar()
        callbackActivity?.showFullscreen()
    }
```

Comment: onActivityCreated deprecated. Пользуйтесь onViewCreated

Comment: Нет активность грузиться уже после этого метода вылетает ошибка

Comment: Во-первых, вы фрагмент не должен знать ничего об activity, у вас кроссзависимость активити от фрагмента и фрагмент от активити. Во-вторых, вместо <fragment> сейчас модно использовать androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView см https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/fragment/NavHostFragment , с ним ошибки не будет. В-третьих, вы надеетесь на соответствие жизненного цикла активити и указанного в разметке фрагмента, почитайте deprecation сообщение про onActivityCreated, и рекомендации по использованию androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver, не копите тех долг.

Comment: Ну да там конечно структура проекта плохая, ее бы по хорошему переписать. Но мне за лишние действия не платили. От себя замечу что фрагмент должен запускаться как отдельная система, но он  знает про активити, потому что нормальная практика использовать интерфейс для обращения к активити, а по сути дела мы то обращаемся к активити пусть даже обходными путями. Вот когда активити к фрагменту обращается (что у меня тоже есть) вот это плохо.

Comment: все с точностью до наоборот. но по крайней мере через интерфейс, это ок. в то же время фрагмент не должен управлять видимостью элементов активити - это дело viewmodel'и.